# Need a Regex expression to get list of strings which start with a word and end in a dot

Tags: c#, regex

I have to parse a string like:

"First Header: some text. more text. extra text. Second Header: blah blah. more blah. Third Header: last bit of text."

and get the following list of strings:

- First Header: some text. more text.
- Second Header: blah blah. more blah.
- Third Header: last bit of text.

How can I do this with Regex? (Im using c#).

So I am looking for text starting with "some random text" + "Header:" and ending with the last dot before the next "Header:"

Comment: You don't need the ^ and $ which indicates that you have only one work per line and you want to search any word on a line.

Comment: The string always starts with sometext, then has the exact word "Header:". That is the word Header with a colon sybol straight after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?:\w*\sHeader:).*?(?=\w+\sHeader:|\.$)/g
```

Matching is done by 3 steps:

1. Begins with "something + Header:"
2. Any text
3. Stops when finds something+header OR a dot at the end of string (to
   capture the last sentence)